# Is there a way to set ALT for IMG / TITLE for LINK in the Comodo Logo?

Tags: javascript, lighthouse

I know this rather trivial, but - If you LightHouse in Chrome to run an Audit, it doesn't like the fact your using the comodo logo without 'alt' tags or a name for the link.  Is there a way to add an alt tag or link title? I tried using -

`image.setAttribute("alt","alt_title_tag");`

`````
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ 
var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? 
"https://secure.trust-provider.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + 
"trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' 
type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> TrustLogo("https://www.yourdomain.com/images/comodo_secure_seal_113x59_transp.png", "CL1", "none");````
</script>
<a href="https://ssl.comodo.com" id="comodoTL">SSL Certificates</a>
</body>
`````

error: Image elements do not have [alt] attributes / Links do not have a discernible name.

Comment: You could just skip the Comodo logo entirely. These site seals are worthless.

Comment: It's a EV cert.

Comment: Irrelevant. You still don't need a site seal on your site. Comodo just wants you to use one as it's free advertising for them. (EV certs are [mostly worthless](https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-dead/), too.)

Comment: Thanks. That's a very good read/article. One thing that is not pointed out in the article besides cert company promo and the price is the fact that a EV certificate is MUCH more difficult to obtain from the issuer (Comodo) and the process is a major pain. It requires that you prove your company identity through a bunch of hoops and if the company is not legit it won't be easy. Real business license up-to-date, phone number, valid address, etc. It's not easy. I've applied for a few. It's for legal websites. Still... They have been issued & Google doesn't like the alt/title config in Lighthouse.

Comment: You can still use the EV cert and drop it when it comes up for renewal. Removing the seal in the meantime will fix the alt/title issue.

Comment: That's not really what the question was about. Anyone who has an EV cert in the meantime who does Not drop the seal will have this same issue if it matters.

Comment: My advice to them would be the same - drop the seal. They're pointless, and your EV cert will work fine without it on your site. Bad code is par for the course with Comodo, in my experiences with them.